# how to send online html or css or js file back up in each hour to and email address as a attachment?

Tags: email, backup, html, css

For example this a css file

http://sstatic.net/su/all.css

I want to send this file from this link as a email attachment to an email address in each hour or any specified time interval.

and to download on local PC in a specified folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send online html or css or js file back up in each hour to and email address as a attachment?](http://superuser.com/questions/98516/how-to-send-online-html-or-css-or-js-file-back-up-in-each-hour-to-and-email-addre)

Comment: @mehper: good find.  @metal gear solid: please don't doublepost your questions.  merging this into the duplicate.

Comment: @quack quixote - but both are same and one question

Comment: those comments were originally posted to http://superuser.com/questions/103675/how-to-take-backup-of-any-online-file-in-email -- that was the doublepost that got merged.  the merge link is available in the revision history of this post: http://superuser.com/posts/98516/revisions

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can start crontab editing with `crontab -e` and add a following line: `0 * * * * wget http://sstatic.net/su/all.css -O /backups/all.css && uuencode /backups/all.css all.css | sendmail your@email.com`. This will update CSS and send emails every hour.

uudecode and sendmail are only for example, you may use other email client/server.

Answer (score 0):

try using a 'web cron':

- http://www.setcronjob.com/